# VBA Excel Date formatting assistance

Tags: vba, excel

So, I've run into the typical date formatting issue.

Which is causing me a headache. 
I can't share the data for security reasons. But, I can describe the format. 
The VBA is simple enough, and she be able to be worked out.

In short,

My macro obtains its data from Col C, where the regex extracts the department and date.

I then call these in a loop to paste the data into Col A, B and finally C to replace the original data.

My issue is, Col B has a date in it. 
It is extracted as "02/04/2018", but when it pastes it into the col, it appears as 04/02/2018. Which is a massive issue.

I cannot get the VBA macro to hold, or set the format. So far.

I will attach my script below and you can let me know.

Thanks!

Ps. This is the line I suspect is the issue.
 `ws.Range("B" & x).Value = match.SubMatches(3)`

I cannot figure out how to have it set the value as extracted from the string. sigh.

```
Sub Link()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim matches As Variant, match As Variant
    Dim Reg_Exp As Object
    Dim rValue As String

    Set Reg_Exp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    Reg_Exp.Pattern = "([\s\S]+?):\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*-\s*([A-z]+)\s*,\s*([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})\b"


    Set ws = Sheet2

    lastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 1 To lastRow
        Set matches = Reg_Exp.Execute(CStr(ws.Range("C" & x).Value))
        If matches.Count > 0 Then
            For Each match In matches
                ws.Range("A" & x).Value = match.SubMatches(3) & match.SubMatches(1)
                ws.Range("B" & x).Value = match.SubMatches(3)
                ws.Range("C" & x).Value = match.SubMatches(1)
            Next match
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: "It is extracted as '02/04/2018'" - What line extracts this?  The `Set matches = ...`?  When pasting why not do say `Range("A1").Value = Month(matches.value) & "/" & Day(matches.value) & "/" & Year(matches.value)`

Comment: `Format` command in VBA. But you may also need the correct formatting to the Excel cells.

Comment: Even though you cannot share the data, you could create dummy data that replicates the problem.  It might also be useful to know which dates are passed unchanged.  They might be dates where one of the first two sections is `>12`

Answer (score 0):

You have provided an ambiguous date. `02/04/2018`, depending on your locale, could be either `04-Feb-2018` or `02-Apr-2018`.

Exactly how to fix your problem depends on your locale settings.

However, what you can do is create an unambiguous date by extracting separately the month, day and year, and creating a date from that.

Change your regex pattern to split out date parts separately.

```
([\s\S]+?):\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*-\s*([A-z]+)\s*,\s*([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})\b
```

Then add into your code lines like this:

```
Dim DT as Date
... your regex stuff ...

With mc(0)
    'DT = DateSerial(.SubMatches(5), .SubMatches(3), .SubMatches(4))
    '  or
    'DT = DateSerial(.SubMatches(5), .SubMatches(4), .SubMatches(3))
End With
```

Choose the appropriate line depending on whether the date in your original data is MDY or DMY format.

You can then write `DT` to the appropriate part of your worksheet, and format the cell as you wish.